# How to limit the size allocated memory?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

While studying pointers I found that if I allocate memory for a 2 digit int I can give that int a higher value. Can someone explain me why it works like that and how to work around it?

Here is the code:

```
int *p;

p = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
p = 123456;
```

Comment: 1. Don't cast `malloc`. Ever 2. What do you think this code actually does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

That said, here, you're just overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Don't do that. It will cause memory leak. Also, if you try to dereference this pointer later, you may face [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as there is no guarantee that this pointer points to a *valid* memory location. Accessing invalid memory leads to UB.

Finally, to address

> *I allocate memory for a 2 digit int [...]*

let me tell you, you are allocating memory to hold two *integers*, not a *two digit integer*. Also, to store the integer values *into* the memory area pointed by the pointer, you need to dereference the pointer, like `*p` and store (assign) the value there, like `*p=12345;`.

`malloc()` allocates memory of the size of *bytes* passed as it's argument. Check the `sizeof(int)` (*and `2*sizeof(int),` if you want*) to make it more clear.

Regarding this, quoting `C11`, chapter

> `void *malloc(size_t size);`
>
> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` [...]

So, here, `malloc()` returns a pointer with the size of two integers (i.e., capable of holding two integer values), not two *digits* or *bytes*.

Also, it's always a good practice to check the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer to avoid the possible UB by dereferencing NULL in case of `malloc()` failure.

Comment: thanks, after reading your answer i have a better understanding of how it works

Comment: @zoNNN You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting any answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Comment: OK, now may I ask for the reason behind the downvote?

Comment: if i have : char *n; n = (char *) malloc(21*sizeof(char));*n = "something"; will this work?

Comment: @zoNNN 1) you did not read the very first line of my answer....... 2) `"something"` is a string literal, which gives a pointer (`char *`) to it's first element while used in RHS of assignment, so in that case, you neither need to allocate memory using malloc, nor dereference the pointer.

Comment: @zoNNN for a simple example, `int *p; p=malloc(2*sizeof(int)); if (p) { *p = 123456};` is a valid code snippet.

Comment: how im a overwriting the pointer returned by malloc()? with (char *) before?

Comment: @zoNNN nopes, by _assigning_ to the pointer. Consider a scalar variable, and let';s do `int x; x = 10; x = 20;`, so, aren't you overwriting the `10` there? Is it clear now?

Comment: @zoNNN When you write `p = 123456;` you are overwriting the pointer `p` itself. If you wrote `*p = 123456;` instead, then you would be overwriting `*p`, which means "the memory that `p` points to".

Answer (score 2):

> if i allocate memory for a 2 digit int i can give that int a higher value.

No, you cannot. You have allocated memory for two `int`s, with full `int` range. Standard guarantees at least five digits (2<sup>15</sup>-1), but on most modern systems you are safe with eight digits (2<sup>31</sup>-1).

Back to your question, there is no way in C to ensure that your program does not write past the end of the memory that it allocates. It is the responsibility of your program to not do that, including any checks it must perform in order to catch potentially unsafe access.

This is called *undefined behavior*. The system may crash when you access memory past the end of the allocated area, but it does not have to.

Comment: thanks for the info, really simple and easy to understand :D

Answer (score 0):

> allocate memory for a 2 digit int

`malloc(2*sizeof(int))` allocates memory for *two integers*, not for a *single two-digit integer*.

Answer (score -1):

1. you do not need the cast in the first place
2. You are allocated memory for two integers - typically 32 bits each
3. You are giving a pointer the value 123456

Perhaps reread the  book